# Is the following set of complex matrices a field?

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $a$ and $z$ be complex numbers, consider $F$ the set of all matrices of the following form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a\cos(z) & -a\sin(z) \\  
a\sin(z) &  a\cos(z) ]\end{bmatrix}  $$

I am fairly confident $F$ is closed under multiplication and that all non zero elements are invertible however I'm not sure it is closed under addition. If it is a field, is it isomorphic to anything simpler?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\sqrt{2}$, $z=\frac{\pi}4$, then we obtain $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Now, let $a=1$, $z=0$, then we obtain $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Add them up, I will leave the task of verifying that the matrix is not in the set as an exercise.